# Sametime plugin development on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, plugins, sametime

I want to start plugin development for IBM SameTime softphone on Mac. But I have problems with setting up the development environment. I tried to do this step by step according to the manual "Setting up the Development Environment" from the IBM site, but I can't install the necessary Expeditor toolkit and IBM Lotus Sametime Connect SDK on Mac. I used the latest version of Eclipse IDE Neon.

Does anybody have experience on plugin development for SameTime on Mac? Please, help me to setup development environment.

I will try specify my problem:

1. Download and install Eclipse IDE Neon on Mac
2. Download Expeditor toolkit file and unzip it in any folder
3. Start Eclipse
4. Go Help->Install new software
5. Click Add->Local and select folder with Expeditor toolkit
6. Click Ok and select all packages.
7. Click Next
8. You will see next error:

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.2.20100816-1002 (com.ibm.pvc.tools.composite-feature.feature.group 6.2.2.20100816-1002)
  Missing requirement: Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.2.20100816-1002 (com.ibm.pvc.tools.composite-feature.feature.group 6.2.2.20100816-1002) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.4.0,3.5.0)' but it could not be found

Please, look at the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: By 'can't install' do you mean there is no download for the Mac? If so you are stuck.

Comment: I have added more info to my question. I hope now it is more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of the error is "requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.common [3.4.0,3.5.0)'".

This is telling you that the `org.eclipse.equinox.common` plugin is required with a version of at least 3.4.0 and less that 3.5.0.

Only Eclipse 3.4 has a version of the plugin which meets these requirements. It seems that the software you are trying to install is very old.